# Avro Schema vs. Scala Case Class for Spark Datasets

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I am curious if there is any significant performance difference between using schemas defined in Scala case classes versus defining schemas with Apache Avro for Spark Datasets. Currently I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
root
 |-- uniqueID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fieldCount: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- fieldImportance: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- fieldPrimaryName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fieldSecondaryName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- samples: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- value1: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value2: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value3: byte (nullable = false)
```

With the corresponding case class looking like

```
case class FieldSample(uniqueID: String, 
                       fieldCount: Int, 
                       fieldImportance: Int,
                       fieldPrimaryName: Int,
                       fieldSecondaryName: Int, 
                       samples: Map[String, ValueStruct])

case class ValueStruct(value1: Byte,
                       value2: Byte,
                       value3: Byte)
```

I have this implemented using scala case classes, but am seeing a pretty large bottleneck on the read from disk. The data is saved on disk in parquet format. What I am wondering is if there is any performance benefits to using Avro schema's as opposed to scala case classes in this case. My guess is that the nested schema is causing parquet to read slowly, so I am wondering if Avro serialization gives any performance upgrades in that manner. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I have not found a definitive answer yet, but empirically there does not seem to be a significant performance difference.